# Node install error

Tags: node.js, terminal

Im trying to install node + npm using brew and keep getting the following:

$brew install node
Warning: node-0.10.33_1 already installed, it's just not linked

Any ideas whats going on and how to fix?

Comment: What happens when you run `brew link node`?  Could be a permissions issue.

Comment: Getting this:     ⚙  ~  brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.33_1...
Error: Could not symlink include/node/ares.h
/usr/local/include/node is not writable.

Comment: You need to fix your permissions.  Run `brew doctor`.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled node but npm is nott installing

Answer (score 2):

Try `brew doctor` that should give you some idea of what the problem is. Also, I *strongly* recommend not installing node directly using brew, but actually installing `nvm` through (`brew install nvm`)

`nvm` is the node version manager, which allows you to install different versions of node, and quickly swap between them.

Comment: nvm notes that you shouldn't use brew to install it on the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

but I try lots method (e.g. nvm, uninstall, brew doctor, blabla...), and decide use http://nodejs.org/ pkg instead.

it would install perfectly without homebrew.

but if you are so likely use homebrew, I have no idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.  It was due to part of a leftover installation from running and using the pkg installer from nodejs.org.  Simply:

```
brew uninstall node
rm -rf /usr/local/include/node
brew install node
```

And you're good to go.  You could probably get away with skipping the uninstall and just performing a `brew link node`, but I didn't try that.